# how to save click event data and use it after page refresh?

Tags: jquery, html, events

I have a site that uses Iframe as a page opening location which means my main page never refresh.
I am using a GQuery code which changes a few elements using data from the click event and it works just fine with the iframe.

Now i want to change my Iframe into a div which means that the page will refresh each time i press a menu link to a different page.

My problem is that once refresh is over and page is ready my click event is gone and i'm missing the data i need to do other actions which require data from the click event.

How can i save the click event data pass the refresh? (href,this and everything else related)

Thanks

Comment: either add it as a query string, or pass it on to a cookie, of course both depending on what data you need to keep...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ajax if you want to avoid page refresh.
Try jQuery's load function to load the content inside any particular div.
i.e.

```
$('div#div1').load('http://yourdomain.com/ajaxresponse.php?id=<id>');
```

As per your comment, you should post data using ajax method & then refresh the page.

```
$.post('<URL>', <DATA>, function(){
   // code to refresh the page
});
```

Comment: the point of refreshing is that i need the URL bar to show each page's URL. if there's a way to change the url without actually refreshing the page that would be the best thing

Comment: In that case, I will prefer to save data in server's session using ajax & reuse it.